# Getting the error ../node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I'm learning new angular from the tutorial(https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#inject-message-service). I'm stuck in this while running the application after adding the Services

**../node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'.**

```
    hero.service.ts
---------------------


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()

export class HeroService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

My Angular version and related information are

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.14.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0

    @angular/cli: 1.7.4
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
    @angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
    @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
    @ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
    @ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
    @schematics/angular: 0.3.2
    @schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
    typescript: 2.5.
```

Comment: What is the version of Rxjs and Angular you are using ?

Comment: Check my answer regarding your issue with Rxjs

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are following Angular official guide which is based on Angular 6 and Rxjs 6. There is a breaking change in Rxjs for which you have to import `operators` and `Observable` in a different way now .

In Rxjs 6 the import is like below -

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; // only need to import from rxjs
```

But as you are using Angular 5.2.x most probably you are still using Rxjs 5x version. Due to which your import statement should be like below

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// or 
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Check the below link for complete changelog and instruction to install a compatibility package `rxjs-compat` for upgrading  from angular 5 to 6.

See this link for reference : https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: Changed from 
**import { of } from 'rxjs';** TO
**import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';**  
And it corrected the problem for me thanks.

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.0
@schematics/angular          0.6.0
@schematics/update           0.6.0
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.7.2 - Probably more than you wanted but just to be clear.

Comment: or you can run: npm install -s rxjs-compat. This will let you deploy with the older rxjs syntax, until you update to rxjs 6 standards, then remove rxjs-compat.

Comment: in my case the import { Observable } error points to files under node_modules angular is 6.4.1 rx is 6.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problems with the operators it is the same

Before

```
import { skip } from 'rxjs';
```

After

```
import { skip } from 'rxjs/operators';
```