# Angular- How do I repeat a component with different data?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular 2 app where I want to list off all of the locations in my data (that I pull in with my service).

Inside my parent I plan to list them off with an *ngFor:

```
<ul *ngFor="let location in myservice.locations"></ul>
```

Firstly, is this possible? The component will repeat once for each location, and look the same other than the data.

I'm just not sure where to start. If my service received 4 locations objects each with name, and date data, How can I go about this?

I'm thinking my location (child) component will look something like this?

```
...
export class locationComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private _myserviceService: MyserviceService) {
  }
obj;
ngOnInit(){
var locationname = ; 
var locationdate = ;
    let observable = this._myserviceService.getLocations();
     observable.subscribe(data => {
     this.obj = data
  })}
```

The html will be something like:

```
{{location.locationname}}
{{location.locationdate}}
```

Mainly my question is, how do I make sure I construct my location component so that it can be reused with multiple data objects and I can loop through them?

Thanks!! Let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: I think you can pass the data to child component using `@Input`.  I am not getting what is the main issue. Would you mind creating a stackblitz exmaple and share with us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fveve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). I think this is what you are looking for.

I am passing

```
  [{
    id: 'location 1'
  },{
    id: 'location 2'
  }]
```

using `*ngFor` loop to the child component where each object can be rendered as per the component.

Comment: Great! I see how this would work. I'm getting an error from my service. I'm having trouble importing 'of/observable' and get this message: 
    Module '"/filepath/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'
Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Never mind! Found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230927/getting-the-error-node-modules-rxjs-rx-has-no-exported-member-of/50231643

Comment: @LaurenAH Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the data received form the endpoint will be stored in this.obj ( code : this.obj = data ), then in your html you can

```
<ul *ngFor="let location in obj">
  <li>{{location.locationname}}</li>
  <li>{{location.locationdate}}</li>
</ul>
```

that will show two lines for each location